# Reject two in a row requests (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, express, request, sails.js

Sometimes we need restrict executing repeating requests from a user if the first request has not been finished. For example: We do want register user at some service, and only after that put him into database with external id. I would like to have a service where I can set protected routes.
I have solved this problem by checking flag at request.start() -> and removed it after the request has been completed. Anyway I'm looking for your suggestion guys.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to build this into the route handlers yourself:

```
var inProgress = []
var handleRegisterRoute = function create(req, res, next) {

    var id = req.user.id

    var found = _.find(inProgress, function(item){
      return item = id
    })

    if(found){
        res.send('Dont think twice, its aright')
        return
    } else {
      inProgress.push(id)
      completeRegister()
      inProgress= _.without(inProgress, id);          
      req.send()
      return
    }
}
```

Again this is psuedo code - to the gist of what I would write.  You may need to store the "inprogress" in a better data store referenceable by your entire server farm - some sort of DB.

Comment: if this applies to only one or limited no of controllers,  A global var / db key can be set at start of controller execution and checked for existence. The key must be unset both in case of a success and failure(s).

Comment: unfortunately this won't work if we apply more than one dyno on app. Is there any custom solution on heroku ?